# open file via rest api in intellij 2016

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

With Intellij versions older than 2016 it was possible to open a certain file in intellij via a rest api call to intellij.

This feature was used in an amazing play framework plugin to link directly to the correct line in the code from a stacktrace that is displayed in the browser:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-framework-tools/dchhggpgbommpcjpogaploblnpldbmen

Read about it here: 
http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/03/07/the-one-play-framework-productivity-tip-you-should-know-about/

With Intellij versions before 2016, using a URL like 
http://localhost:63342/api/file/D:/John/Documents/GitHub/myapp/app/controllers/Application.scala:14 would work. Intellij would have opened and highlighted the correct line in the correct file.
The URL I used to configure the chrome plugin to generate the above link was: http://localhost:63342/api/file/$file:$line

Currently I am running IntelliJ 2016.1.3 and the setup doesn't work anymore.
Has the Intellij API changed? Should I use a new URL pattern instead of http://localhost:63342/api/file/$file:$line    ?

Comment: Found some documentation for the api: http://develar.org/idea-rest-api/#api-Platform-file   Tried it, still doesn't work on Windows 10, though.

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is related to their [somewhat-recent built-in server security update](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/), but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @nemoo I am not seeing the difference in the URL pattern from the example you show for pre-2016 and the 'new URL pattern'.  I am having the same problem that you are.  Suddenly URLs that opened files in the IDE just fine are getting a 404.

Comment: Yes, the url pattern is the same. My assumption is that the implementation behind it has changed with IntelliJ2016

Comment: update: tried again, now using Intellij 2016.2.2. now it works again.

Comment: yes, seems both your-like URL and like this http://localhost:63342/api/file?file=D:/John/Documents/GitHub/myapp/app/controllers/Application&line=14&column=5 works now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with PHPStorm, maybe my solution also works for IntelliJ:

You need to go into Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Debugger.
There you should find a section called "Built-in server". The port number that's specified there is the one you should use (localhost:63342 is the default). Also you might have to check "Allow unsigned requests". They added this checkbox after their security update.