# JetBrains IDEs internal web server API stopped working as expected (on latest 2022.3.1 WebStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

IntelliJ based IDEs running [built-in web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php-built-in-web-server.html), usually running on port 63342.

The supposedly supported API can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a77365debaadcf00b888a977d89512f3f0f3cf9e/platform/built-in-server/src/org/jetbrains/ide/OpenFileHttpService.kt#L52):

```
 * @apiExample {curl} Absolute path
 * curl http://localhost:63342/api/file//absolute/path/to/file.kt
 *
 * @apiExample {curl} Relative path
 * curl http://localhost:63342/api/file/relative/to/module/root/path/to/file.kt
 *
 * @apiExample {curl} With line and column
 * curl http://localhost:63342/api/file/relative/to/module/root/path/to/file.kt:100:34
 *
 * @apiExample {curl} Query parameters
 * curl http://localhost:63342/api/file?file=path/to/file.kt&line=100&column=34
```

[or pretty printed here](https://www.develar.org/idea-rest-api/#api-Platform-openProjectSet).

This API worked perfectly fine on WebStorm 2020.3 (I installed it just to check):

[image]

However it stopped working as expected on 2022.1 (or maybe before):

[image]

As a result, any extension based on this API (such [this one](https://github.com/BernieCr/open-in-intellij) I'm using) stopped working.

If the API of the built-in web server has changed, I can't find where it is documented (and chatGPT doesn't know it because it's too new ).

The latest indication I could find that the API was working as expected as described above, is [here](https://antkorwin.com/idea/openfile.html) from 2020/3/16.

Note, this is not a duplicate: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253792/open-file-via-rest-api-in-intellij-2016) thread is old and not relevant, this issue is not related to the security update that required checking 'Allow unsigned requests' in the settings.

Comment: `http://localhost:63342/api/about` works as expected for me in 2022.3.1...

Comment: What might be the problem? Is this a standalone or via jetbrains toolbox?

Comment: `http://localhost:63342/api/about` works fine for me as well in PhpStorm 2022.3.1 on Windows 10. `{ "name" : "PhpStorm 2022.3.1", "productName" : "PhpStorm", "baselineVersion" : 223, "buildNumber" : "223.8214.64" }` Maybe you have disabled some important plugins .. or installed some that are conflicting here. Try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and see how it goes. Ensure that the right port number is used (in case if it's already used by some another app/another copy etc)

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled webstorm and now the problem is solved. not sure if its because of plugins (because I've reinstalled the plugins as well) or because of something related to the way webstorm update it self between versions

Comment: @EliavLouski Consider making an answer then -- may help others in a similar situation (and having an Accepted Answer makes it more visible/discoverable)

Comment: OK, I found the issue. apparently sending specific requests (with particular URL and query params) to the API crashes the API endpoint and in order to make the endpoint work as expected again a restart is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2022.3 `/api/file/` was moved to [IDE Remote Control](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19991-ide-remote-control) plugin, it's now required for the API to work

Comment: if this functionality is not inbuilt it misses the goal completely...

who decided to extract it to a separate plugin and why? it should be bundled with normally